# How to write geopoint data in firebase firestore in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

How to write GeoPoints data like this in Firebase Firestore in Flutter?
[image: Firestore]

I just want to simply store latitue and longitude data

Answer (score 3):

There's a [`GeoPoint` type](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/GeoPoint-class.html) provided by the Flutter Firebase library. You just do this:

```dart
final result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('waypoints')
  .add({
    'startPoint': GeoPoint(5.373982, 2.705164)
  });
```